# How do I transfer an archive pst file from my old Outlook account to Outlook 2016?

Tags: archiving, office365, pst, microsoft-outlook-2016

I recently upgraded from Office 2010 to Office 365. I also upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 10 (my computer was running slow so I reset it, rather than simply upgrading).

I had a large archive folder in my email account so before I installed Windows 10 I saved the archive pst file on a NAS so that I could re-install it once I was up and running with Outlook 2016.

I don't know what to do next. How do I now add the archive pst file back into my email account?

It's an IMAP email account.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In Outlook 2016, click the File tab.

In right pane, click Account Settings, and then click Account Settings.

On the Data Files tab, click Add and browse to your saved archive.pst file and click Open, then close the Account Settings window.

Confirm archive folder is added in the left pane.